# Maps gives error in Apex Class

Tags: apex, map

The following statement gives error. What is the problem?

```
Map<string, customB__c=""> myBMap = new Map<id, customB__c="">();
```

Error is

> Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'Map' at line 11 column 0

Please advice.

Answer (score 9):

You need to declare it like this

```
Map<Id,YourObject> myMap = new Map<Id,YourObject>();
```

[Map](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm) class